# Convergence of Series and Infinite Sums

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Should not all series converge to infinity....if you sum them over infinity?

Comment: "Summing them over infinity" is just a rather imprecise way of saying "taking a limit". Why on earth would you expect every limit of partial sums to be infinite? What if every term in the sum is zero? Would you really expect the limit to be infinite?

Answer (score 2):

No, for a simple example take the series
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty(-1)^n=1-1+1-1+1-\cdots.$$
Is is easy to see that this is bounded above and below and thus cannot converge to infinity.

Answer (score 1):

No since the contributions from individual terms in any series converging to a finite limit become arbitrarily small (tend to $0$) so the contribution from successive terms is less and less. For an intuitive example of how this can happen see this picture for the series $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty 2^{-n}$

[image]